# How to Git Pull across a local network?

Tags: git, pull

I have a Git repository configured on my work machine at `C:\Projects\project_1`.

I have shared the `Projects` folder on our work network and a colleague has cloned my `project_1` into his own `C:\Projects` folder, which he has also shared.

We've both been working on the source code contained within the project and now I want to pull his changes into my repository.

I am using TortoiseGit and have tried pulling using the arbitrary URL `\\HIS_COMPUTER\Projects\project_1`, but I get the following error message:

`fatal: '\\HIS_COMPUTER\Projects\project_1" master' does not appear to be a git repository`

`fatal: Could not read from remote repository.`

Can anyone provide some assistance on performing the pull? I have had a look at folder permissions and they all seem ok.

Comment: Can you open `\\HIS_COMPUTER\Projects` in Windows Explorer?  (Just type it into the address bar.)

Comment: @Andomar: Yes, I can.

Comment: The error message suggests you are trying to load `\\HIS_COMPUTER\Projects\project_1" master` as a repository.  Perhaps omit the `" master` part?

Comment: Map `\\HIS_COMPUTER\Projects\` to a drive letter, and pull from that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @Andomar for his answer:

I needed to map the network drive `\\HIS_COMPUTER\Projects` to `Z:\` and perform the pull using this as the arbitrary URL.